# Showing a 404 error when navigating to another page

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

so I have built a website and I successfully upload it to a shared hosting that uses **Plesk**
the home page loads and it works but whenever I try to navigate to another page I get this error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

is their any thing that i can add or change in my .htacceess  file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
##
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

how can I fix this problem

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. According to the error message, you are not using Apache, but IIS

Comment: To clarify @NicoHaase's comment, htaccess files are config files for Apache web server, not IIS (which uses something called web.config which looks completely different)

Comment: I have shared every thing that is shown to me @NicoHaase

Comment: Okay, then to clarify: you cannot configure the given webserver using `.htaccess` - either change the webserver, such that you can use the same Apache you are probably using in your local environment, or adjust your configuration to the IIS webserver your hoster provides

Comment: any idea on how can I use IIS configuration @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

so the problem was I was using Apache on my localhost and my hosting is using IIS
the solution is to use **web.config** file insted of **.htaccess**